# Catch all exceptions in Scala 2.8 RC1

Tags: scala, warnings, exception, try-catch, catch-all

I have the following dummy Scala code in the file `test.scala`:

```
class Transaction {
  def begin() {}
  def commit() {}
  def rollback() {}
}

object Test extends Application {
  def doSomething() {}

  val t = new Transaction()
  t.begin()
  try {
    doSomething()
    t.commit()
  } catch {
    case _ => t.rollback()
  }
}
```

If I compile this on Scala 2.8 RC1 with `scalac -Xstrict-warnings test.scala` I'll get the following warning:

```
test.scala:16: warning: catch clause swallows everything: not advised.
    case _ => t.rollback()
    ^
one warning found
```

So, if catch-all expressions are not advised, how am I supposed to implement such a pattern instead? And apart from that why are such expressions not advised anyhow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning exists because you probably don't want to catch everything.  For example, it's generally inadvisable to try to catch anything in `java.lang.Error` since it's often hard to recover from such things.  (Chances are good that you'll be thrown out of your catch block with another exception.)

Also, because you can't usefully catch everything, this isn't a safe way to implement atomic/failsafe transactions.  You're better off with something like

```
try {
  t.commit()
} finally {
  if (!t.checkCommitted()) {
    t.rollback()
    if (!t.checkRolledback()) throw new FUBARed(t)
  }
}
```

with additional testing when reading in a new `t` to make sure it's in a sensible state.

Comment: OK. This one works for transactions. But what if I want to completely ignore an exception thrown by a method just because it doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: You can `catch { case _: Exception => }`.  `Error` is `Throwable` but not an `Exception`--usually better to go through.  If you really mean, "I don't care if I attempt and fail to catch this, I at least want to give it my best shot", then you can live with the (strict) warning message.  That's why it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! You're right, that catching `Error` is not really what I want :-)

Comment: For catch-all handlers, you should probably prefer using `NonFatal` (see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.NonFatal$). This will integrate better with scala. In particular, this won't interfer with returns from within a closure, which under the hood throws a `NonLocalReturnControl`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - Indeed, that's the way to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a compiler to hand to test this, but shouldn't you be re-throwing the exception after rolling back the transaction? i.e. this should be

```
val t = new Transaction()
t.begin()
try {
  doSomething()
  t.commit()
} catch {
  case e => t.rollback(); throw e
}
```

If you are catching all exceptions, you should take note of [the documentation for `ControlThrowable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/rc-api/scala/util/control/ControlThrowable.html).  Presumably you want your transaction to roll back on abnormal termination, but wouldn't want it to roll back for a non-local return or a `util.control.Breaks.break`.  If so, you might want to do something like the following:

```
val t = new Transaction()
t.begin()
try {
  doSomething()
  t.commit()
} catch {
  case ce : ControlThrowable => throw ce // propagate
  case e => t.rollback(); throw e        // roll-back and propagate
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code still leads to the abovementioned warning.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that this is a warning, not an error. And even so, an warning raised only with the -Xstrict-warings option. In other words, it means that **maybe** you are doing a logic mistake, but it is up to you to decide.

As others have noticed, in most cases it is not meaningful to catch all exception and you should do something like this:

```
t.begin()
try {
  doSomething()
  t.commit()
} catch {
  case e: DuplicatedKeyError => ...
  case e: BrokenConnectionError => ...
  case e: DumbInputDetectedError => ...
}
```

i.e. handle meaningfuly all known error types.

But if you are positive that you want to ignore (or handle the same way) all possible exceptions, then just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch `Throwable` to state your intent of catching all:

```
  try {
     android.util.Log.i (TAG, "Feature " + Text)
     statements
  }
  catch {
     case exception: Throwable =>
        val Message = "Feature " + Text + "failed"
        android.util.Log.e (TAG, Message, exception)
        fail (Message)
  } // try
```

The example above if from a piece of unit test. As the warning says: **not advised in normal code**